# Finding ArgMin of the function with undefined constants

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a problem which I can solve on the paper, but I want to be able to solve in *Mathematica*:

> **Find argument of the minimum of the following function:**
>   [image: problem]

So on paper my solutuon goes like this:

> [image: > [![mysolution][2]][2]]

So in *Mathematica* I tried:

`f = Function[x, Sum[(x - Indexed[t, k])^2, {k, 1, n}]]
Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]`

and I've got this result:

`{{x -> InverseFunction[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(n\)]\(2\ \((x - \*
TemplateBox[{"t","k"},
"IndexedDefault"])\)\)\), 1, 1][0]}}`

Is there a method to get a solution like the one I calculated manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think it's worth the trouble, you can do the following  (`InputForm` only to make the output clearer)

```
Sum[(x - t[k])^2, {k, 1, n}] // InputForm
(* Sum[(x - t[k])^2, {k, 1, n}] *)

D[%, x] == 0 // InputForm
(* Sum[2*(x - t[k]), {k, 1, n}] == 0 *)

% /. u__Sum :> Evaluate //@ MapAt[Expand, u, 1] // InputForm
(* Sum[2*x - 2*t[k], {k, 1, n}] == 0 *)

Distribute /@ % // InputForm
(* 2*n*x + Sum[-2*t[k], {k, 1, n}] == 0 *)

% /. HoldPattern[Sum[u_ v_?(FreeQ[#, k] &), {k, 1, n}]] :> v Sum[u, {k, 1, n}] // InputForm
(* 2*n*x - 2*Sum[t[k], {k, 1, n}] == 0 *)

Solve[%, x] // InputForm
(* {{x -> Sum[t[k], {k, 1, n}]/n}} *)
```

It *might* be worth doing this sort of thing for more complicated expressions.

*EDIT*

If you want to do this without doing a manual minimisation, Mathematica can solve it if you force `x` outside the summation.  For example:

```
Sum[(x - t[k])^2, {k, 1, n}];
% /. u__Sum :> Evaluate //@ MapAt[Expand, u, 1] // InputForm
(* Sum[x^2 - 2*x*t[k] + t[k]^2, {k, 1, n}] *)

Distribute[%] // InputForm
(* n*x^2 + Sum[-2*x*t[k], {k, 1, n}] + Sum[t[k]^2, {k, 1, n}] *)

% /. HoldPattern[Sum[u_ v_?(FreeQ[#, k] &), {k, 1, n}]] :> 
   v Sum[u, {k, 1, n}] // InputForm
(* n*x^2 - 2*x*Sum[t[k], {k, 1, n}] + Sum[t[k]^2, {k, 1, n}] *)

Assuming[n > 0, ArgMin[%, x] // Refine] // InputForm
(* Piecewise[{{Sum[t[k], {k, 1, n}]/n, Sum[t[k], {k, 1, n}] > 0 || 
    Sum[t[k], {k, 1, n}] < 0}}, 0] *)
```

The use of `Piecewise` at the end is a little irritating, but getting rid of that is a separate question [Piecewise[] merge equivalent conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127447/36788)

Comment: Thanks! But still it i am interested if there is a way to solve this equation without explicitly specifying the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty close to what you would do by hand:

```
allT = Array[t, 5];
der[x_] := D[Sum[(x - t[i])^2, {i, Length[allT]}], x];
Solve[der[x] == 0, x]

{{x -> 1/5 (t[1] + t[2] + t[3] + t[4] + t[5])}}
```

Comment: How do you make the number of terms in the sum a *variable* $n$, not a fixed constant (e.g., $5$)?

Comment: I took the "undefined constants" to be the $t_k$. I doubt you can do it without specifying the size of the data, though I would be pleased to find out I am wrong.

Comment: thanks, but i am interested in finding solution with a variable n.