# Piecewise[] merge equivalent conditions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise

Is there a simple way to merge equivalent conditions in `Piecewise`?  For example, in the following we have (trivially) `pw==x`.

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x, x != 0}}, 0];
```

Is there some way to force this without cheating?  I would call the following cheating:

```
Assuming[x != 0, Refine[pw]]
(* x *)
```

As a further example, can I get the simplification (for `x` real) `pw2==Abs[x]`?

```
pw2 = Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}}, -x];
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, we have

```
Simplify[Piecewise[{{x, x != 0}}, 0], x ∈ Reals]
(*  x  *)
```

In the second case, `Abs[x]` is a function of a complex variable and will not be treated as equivalent to `Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}}, -x]`.  (This seems correct to me.)  If one wants the standard real absolute value, one can add a domain to [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html):

```
PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], Reals]
(*  Piecewise[{{-x, x < 0}}, x]  *)
```

Comment: Oops -- wait -- maybe in the first case, `x` was supposed to be complex?

Comment: @ +1 for a useful partial answer.  Any insight on why an irrelevant assumption (`x` real) helps with the first case?  In the second example, I was interested in the case with `x` real (I think this is implicit in any expression involving an inequality).  In this case, I think the expression `Abs[x]` is a reasonable simplification result - just as `Abs[x]` simplifies to `x` when I assumes `x>0`.

Comment: @mikado Not really. I thought of it immediately, actually, but I think it was for a bogus reason (now kinda forgotten -- something like the `Abs[]` example). Note that `UnsameQ` instead of `Unequal` works without the assumption: `Simplify[Piecewise[{{x, x =!= 0}}, 0]]`. -- What I've noticed about `Abs[]` is that *M* will simplify it to something else when `x` is real or positive, etc., but it will not go from an expression to `Abs[]`. I suppose there's not a strong argument why this behavior is preferably, but I almost never want `Abs[x]` when `x` is real (differentiating it is a pain).